# Where I can find example in using v4l2 codec driver

Tags: v4l2

in Raspberry-Pi code, there is a `s5p-jpeg` codec driver.

```
drivers/media/platform/s5p-jpeg/jpeg-core.c
```

Can sombody please tell me where I can find an example of how to use it?
Or any other v4l2 codec driver?

I have googled for it, but I cannot find any example which uses a v4l2 codec driver.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: what do you want to acchieve? what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to use a v4l2 codec driver. How to pass in an input image and how to get an output image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(adding another answer, since it's completely different :-))

A "codec" API in the V4L2 specs, refers to hardware codecs.
such a codec is a device that has the following features:

- the hardware codec shows up as a `/dev/videoX` device
- it has a video input, where you're userland application can send a video-stream - e.g. containing JPEG-encoded video frames - to, so it has the `V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_OUTPUT` capability and
- it has a video output, where you're userland application can read a video-stream - e.g. containing the uncompressed frames - from, so it also has the `V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_CAPTURE` capability.

There are numerous applications that can write video to a v4l2 OUTPUT device, here are a few that i know of:

- [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/)'s `v4l2sink` element
- [LiVeS](http://lives.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gem](http://gem.iem.at)
- ...

afaik, these application don't have any specific code to deal with "v4l2 codec devices", but can write to/read from v4l2 devices, which is all that you should need.

Also check the [v4l-utils.git](http://linuxtv.org): Look in utils/v4l2-ctl/v4l2-ctl-streaming.cpp

Answer (score 2):

v4l2 is very liberal when it comes to formats: e.g. capture devices can deliver frames in virtually any format.

So if you are writing a user-land tool (application, library,...; as opposed to a kernel-driver), *though shalt not fiddle with codecs* (if you can avoid it).
Imagine each and every application in the world that wants to read v4l2-streams, having to add code to decode frames in `SQ905C` or `MJPEG` or whatnot codec (each application adding their own set of buggy implementation)

Instead, smart people created a library which will decompress the frames delivered by your capture device and provide these frames in a standard way: [libv4l2](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/libv4l.html).

Incidentally, if you insist on writing your own code, `libv4l2` is a good reference implementation.

Oh, and if you were thinking about simpy loading a module to the encoding/decoding in kernel-space (e.g. *you have webcam "foo" which delivers images in format "XYZ" but you want it to deliver images in format "ABC" by means of adding a kernel-module*) then you are out of luck.

Linus T. has been quite clear [missing reference] that codec conversion code is not to be run within kernel-space.

Comment: I am writing a user land tool and I want to learn how to use I have been googled it, so far I can't find anything which uses v4l2 codec. All the example i find are for video capture.

Answer (score 0):

The code [here](https://github.com/6by9/v4l2_m2m/blob/master/m2m.c) accesses a v4l2 codec driver

It indeeds checks the V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_M2M cap

It is based on the [kernel capture example](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/media/v4l/capture.c.html) but with some extra code